# js recursive function with for in

Tags: javascript

There are call function with reqursive in for .. in loop, but something wrong in work. As I think reason in loop but I can not understand why. Help somebody!

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Test html with js tasks</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='./2.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var objSample = {
            "glossary": {
                "title": "example glossary",
                "GlossDiv": {
                    "title": "S",
                    "GlossList": {
                        "GlossEntry": {
                            "ID": "SGML",
                            "SortAs": "SGML",
                            "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                            "Acronym": "SGML",
                            "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                            "GlossDef": {
                                "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                                "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                            },
                            "GlossSee": "markup"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        findProperty(objSample, 'SGML');
    </script>
    Pikabu
</body>
</html>
```

and source code for 2.js:

```js
function findProperty(obj, propContentPart) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            if (findProperty(value, propContentPart)) {
                console.log(key);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (value.indexOf(propContentPart) > -1){
                console.log(key);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output is:

```
ID
GlossEntry
GlossList
GlossDiv
glossary
```

But expected also SortAs and Acronym. Why so?

Comment: When you find a matching item you are `return`ing from the function. The rest of the loop won't get executed. Hence no `SortAs` or `Acronym`. And do you actually want `GlossEntry`, `GlossList`, `GlossDiv` and `glossary`? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I try to log path of each property which will contain passed propContentPart. You're right after first `return` we consistently come out of the chain of reqursive. But why just we aren't shifted to previous level of chain of reqursive? Why we go out immediately?

Answer (score 0):

1. Be careful when using typeof, for example, using typeof on array gives 'object'. I would prefer using instanceof Object for checking if the requester prop is an object.
2. indexOf works only for arrays, not for objects. To give the expected results, "SortAs": "SGML" and "Acronym": "SGML" should be arrays: "Acronym": ["SGML"]